# Replicate redis into Elasticache

Tags: redis, replication, amazon-elasticache

I want to migrate my redis instances into Elasticache.

I am well aware that one can copy an RDB file into S3 and use that to seed the EC redis. I'm looking for a different approach.

Ideally, I want to replicate data from my production redis straight into EC. It is NOT possible to I set EC instances as slaves (and replicate into them using Redis's built in replication) but perhaps there are alternatives?

I can think of a few ways to do this:

1. intercept the communication between redis-client(s) and redis, and stream the commands to EC
2. setup a slave outside EC and intercept the master-slave communication between them - parse it back to commands and stream that to EC.
3. yet another option is this: run an application that mocks the slave-side of redis and transmit each command from it to another redis. a mock slave server has been implemented in jscript: https://github.com/jmealo/redis-sync, but I'm not sure how ready it is for actual production load

the 2nd approach is harder but solves the problem of having to deal with multiple clients. Is anyone aware of existing tools that can do this? Or any other ideas?

Comment: actually, we found out that AWS does offer replication into Elasticache, as a 'secret API'. if you need this solution, try contacting them.

Comment: Can I know secret API :)?

Comment: the api isn't 'secret' - its disabled. talk to your aws contact.